# sql query postgres count nested loop bad performances

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-performance

Hi I can't seem to find the right answer so I might as well write a post

Could any db expert help me improve the following query (see explain plan) which is slowing down our application on production quite a bit.

- a bid is related to a realty
- a realty is owned by an agency
- I'm using postgres
- a table stores the views per user: HIT(user_id, bid_id, date)

the aim is to retrieve the number of hits per bids for a
   particular agency

here is the query

```
select hit.bid_id , count(hit.id)
from hit
  cross join bid
  cross join realty
where hit.bid_id=bid.id
  and realty.id=bid.realty_id
  and realty.agency_id = 91
group by hit.bid_id
order by count(hit.id) desc
```

here is the explain plan

```
"Sort  (cost=167474.69..167493.30 rows=7445 width=16)"
"  Sort Key: (count(hit.id)) DESC"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=166921.45..166995.90 rows=7445 width=16)"
"        Group Key: hit.bid_id"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=694.81..162541.34 rows=876021 width=16)"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=694.38..7217.46 rows=1986 width=8)"
"                    Hash Cond: (bid.realty_id = realty.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on bid  (cost=0.00..6398.98 rows=27798 width=16)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=669.92..669.92 rows=1957 width=8)"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on realty  (cost=63.45..669.92 rows=1957 width=8)"
"                                Recheck Cond: (agency_id = 91)"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on agency_idx  (cost=0.00..62.97 rows=1957 width=0)"
"                                      Index Cond: (agency_id = 91)"
"              ->  Index Scan using hit_bid_id_idx on hit  (cost=0.43..61.74 rows=1647 width=16)"
"                    Index Cond: (bid_id = bid.id)"
```

I tried to use exists, or select in but they are worse

[EDIT]
I'm using QueryDsl (java api) which generates the cross joins, but even with inner join the execution plan is too long, 
here is the explain plan with verbose

```
"Sort  (cost=169479.60..169498.99 rows=7756 width=16) (actual time=15350.858..15351.819 rows=821 loops=1)"
"  Output: hit.bid_id, (count(hit.id))"
"  Sort Key: (count(hit.id)) DESC"
"  Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 63kB"
"  ->  HashAggregate  (cost=168900.96..168978.52 rows=7756 width=16) (actual time=15348.418..15349.550 rows=821 loops=1)"
"        Output: hit.bid_id, count(hit.id)"
"        Group Key: hit.bid_id"
"        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=699.70..164385.85 rows=903022 width=16) (actual time=17.777..14364.165 rows=582723 loops=1)"
"              Output: hit.bid_id, hit.id"
"              ->  Hash Join  (cost=699.26..7225.23 rows=2013 width=8) (actual time=8.427..146.966 rows=1977 loops=1)"
"                    Output: bid.id"
"                    Hash Cond: (bid.realty_id = realty.id)"
"                    ->  Seq Scan on public.bid  (cost=0.00..6400.88 rows=27988 width=16) (actual time=0.018..84.389 rows=27994 loops=1)"
"                          Output: bid.id, bid.created_by, bid.created_date, bid.last_modified_by, bid.last_modified_date, bid.agency_costs, bid.availability_begin_date, bid.availability_end_date, bid.bail, bid.description, bid.imported_bid, bid.is_availabl (...)"
"                    ->  Hash  (cost=674.46..674.46 rows=1984 width=8) (actual time=8.186..8.186 rows=1977 loops=1)"
"                          Output: realty.id"
"                          Buckets: 2048  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 94kB"
"                          ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.realty  (cost=67.66..674.46 rows=1984 width=8) (actual time=0.533..4.967 rows=1977 loops=1)"
"                                Output: realty.id"
"                                Recheck Cond: (realty.agency_id = 91)"
"                                Heap Blocks: exact=208"
"                                ->  Bitmap Index Scan on agency_idx  (cost=0.00..67.17 rows=1984 width=0) (actual time=0.491..0.491 rows=1978 loops=1)"
"                                      Index Cond: (realty.agency_id = 91)"
"              ->  Index Scan using hit_bid_id_idx on public.hit  (cost=0.43..61.88 rows=1619 width=16) (actual time=2.198..6.376 rows=295 loops=1977)"
"                    Output: hit.id, hit.created_by, hit.created_date, hit.last_modified_by, hit.last_modified_date, hit.date, hit.ip, hit.user_id, hit.bid_id, hit.display_phone"
"                    Index Cond: (hit.bid_id = bid.id)"
"Planning time: 3.037 ms"
"Execution time: 15353.187 ms"
```

Tables DDL

```
CREATE TABLE public.bid
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  realty_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT bid_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT bid_fkey_realty FOREIGN KEY (realty_id)
      REFERENCES public.realty (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE public.hit
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  bid_id bigint,
  CONSTRAINT hit_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id),
  CONSTRAINT hit_fkey_bid FOREIGN KEY (bid_id)
      REFERENCES public.bid (id) MATCH SIMPLE
      ON UPDATE NO ACTION ON DELETE NO ACTION
)

CREATE TABLE public.realty
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  CONSTRAINT realty_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

Comment: Add the DDL of each table please

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the  execution plan generated using **`explain (analyze, verbose, buffers)`**. But those cross joins don't make any sense. Why don't you just use a regular `join` as apparently that is what you want to do

Comment: thanks, I have edited the post with verbose, the cross joins are generated by QueryDsl (java api) I've tried inner join but the exec plan is pretty similar

Answer (score 0):

You are unnecessarily using cross join, beyond that there is a "seq scan" on the bid table in your explain plan; but the explain plan of the following may be different:

```
select hit.bid_id , count(hit.id)
from hit
  inner join bid ON hit.bid_id=bid.id
  inner join realty ON realty.id=bid.realty_id
where realty.agency_id = 91
group by hit.bid_id
order by count(hit.id) desc
```

while it should not matter, maybe changing the table sequence will have an effect:

```
select hit.bid_id , count(hit.id)
from realty
  inner join bid ON realty.id=bid.realty_id
  inner join hit ON hit.bid_id=bid.id
where realty.agency_id = 91
group by hit.bid_id
order by count(hit.id) desc
```

Can I assume the db statistics are current or "fresh"?

Comment: thanks, I have edited the post, inner join doesn't make any difference, and yes the stats are fresh.

Answer (score 0):

If you provide more information (such as index status, table descriptions, explain plan with more details options), I would suggest more interesting solutions.
But the good solutions will provide from other people. I provide the bad solution but it's helpful at sometimes.

This source is based Java but it apply to the other languages.

It's a temporary work, but you might have effect immediately.

Try it for testing non-nestloop execution plan.

```
PreparedStatement stmt = connect.preparedStatement(
"SET enable_nestloop TO false;" +
"select hit.bid_id , count(hit.id)
from hit
cross join bid
cross join realty
where hit.bid_id=bid.id
and realty.id=bid.realty_id
and realty.agency_id = 91
group by hit.bid_id
order by count(hit.id) desc;" +
"SET enable_nestloop TO true;"
);
```